# How to disable Windows 10 notification video effect

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I recently returned to be a primary Windows user. I'm using Windows 10 Home edition.

One thing that really annoys me is the *invert screen* error notification, especially when using a shell, like the command prompt for instance.

[image]

Is there any way of disabling that?

Comment: I think this is a default-off setting of assistive technologies. You must have turned it on in the past. Here it is described for older Windows: http://etc.usf.edu/techease/4all/hearing/how-do-you-enable-visual-notifications-in-windows-7/#html

Answer (score 0):

Just enable quiet hours and most of Windows 10 notifications will be disabled.

[image]